# Issue installing Amazon RDS Command line tool (RDSCli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS and RDS, I am currently trying to do the seemingly simple task of creating a sql server database. But I'm falling at the first hurdle, actually creating the BD, I cant use the tutorials as they refer to visual studio's AWS UI components which all seem to work apart from the Create DB forms. So I found a command line tool, RDSCli, but I cant get it working. I've followed all the instructions (below) but when i run **rds --help** i just get the following output...

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
-client       to select the "client" VM
-server       to select the "server" VM
-hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
              The default VM is client.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrumen

-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

**README.txt**

## Relational Data Service (RDS) Command Line Tools

### Installation:

1. Ensure that JAVA version 1.6 or higher is installed on your system: (java -version)
2. Unzip the deployment zip file
3. Set the following environment variables:
   3.1 AWS_RDS_HOME - The directory where the deployment files were copied to
       check with:
          Unix: ls ${AWS_RDS_HOME}/bin should list rds-describe-db-instances ...)
          Windows: dir %AWS_RDS_HOME%\bin should list rds-describe-db-instances ...)
   3.2 JAVA_HOME - Java Installation home directory
4. Add ${AWS_RDS_HOME}/bin (in Windows: %AWS_RDS_HOME%\bin) to your path
5. (Unix only) Set execute permissions on all files in the bin directory: chmod +x ${AWS_RDS_HOME}/bin/*

### Configuration:

Provide the command line tool with your AWS user credentials. There are two ways you can provide credentials: AWS keys, or using X.509 certificates.

### Using AWS Keys

1. Create a credential file: The deployment includes a template file ${AWS_RDS_HOME}/credential-file-path.template. Edit a copy of this file to add your information.
    On UNIX, limit permissions to the owner of the credential file: $ chmod 600 .
2. There are several ways to provide your credential information:
     a. Set the following environment variable: AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=
     b. Alternatively, provide the following option with every command --aws-credential-file 
     c. Explicitly specify credentials on the command line: --I ACCESS_KEY --S SECRET_KEY

### Running:

Check that your setup works properly, run the following command:
   $ rds --help
      You should see the usage page for all RDS commands.
   $ rds-describe-db-instances --headers
      If you have database instances already configured, you will see a header line followed by a description line for each database instance.
      If you do not have any database instances yet, the command should simply run with no error output.

Comment: The RDS command line tools only control infrastructure, most of which you can do via the management console. If you want to create a database, you would use your preferred SQL client, connect to the instance and do everything else via SQL.

Comment: I cant connect yet as I haven't set up the security guff, and according to the tutorial you do when when you create a database?

Comment: Keep in mind that creating a database and creating an RDS instance are not the same thing. You can create and manage the instance from the management console. The command line tools are more helpful to access some of the features not available in the console or when you need to automate a bunch of commands.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same problem it it turned out my JAVA_HOME was set up with a trailing slash.  I removed this and it started working fine.

To see the exact command that the script is running go to the {AWS_RDS_HOME}/bin/service.cmd. Add the following line above the same line without the echo.  This will allow you to see the exact statement being called by the script.

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %SERVICE_JVM_ARGS% -classpath %CP% com.amazon.webservices.Cli %CMD% %ARGV%
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %SERVICE_JVM_ARGS% -classpath %CP% com.amazon.webservices.Cli %CMD% %ARGV%
```

You can then try tweaking the command and running directly to see which of your environment parameters are messing with the script.